# Typescript doesn't check object property existence when it is typed as [key: string]

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have typed my object of objects as:

```
export interface ObjectInterface {
  [key: string]: SomeOtherObjectInterface;
}
```

Then let's say I have object like:

```
const obj: ObjectInterface = {
   a: ...,
   b: ...,
}
```

Then when I want to access some object property it is not type-safe:

```
const x = obj.dsdssdsdsds;
```

There is no error within my IDE.

When I remove type from `obj` it throws an error properly. What could be done here to use our type but still get errors like `Property 'dsds' does not exist on type......`

Comment: If you declare it as `ObjectInterface` then you lose the type-safety. I don't know what you expected. Typescript is duck-typed so as long as your object conforms to the interface it'll be considered an implementation of the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript `4.1-beta` has solved this issue.

These is a new option: `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess`.

> Turning on `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` will add undefined to any un-declared field in the type.

You can test it on [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&ts=4.1.0-beta#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgeQCMArYbGASRTS1zgG8BYAKDjgG0BrYATwC44AZxhRkAcwC6ApAFcAtoTQBuFgF8WLbBCTC4EEgKKlyVVBhx4AvAxZs4mAQEYANLbaEBAJlfN1zFvrEAHQA7gCOIcDhwEEwEABiCCDAACYAFACULEA).

Read more: [Announcing TypeScript 4.1 Beta - Pedantic Index Signature Checks (--noUncheckedIndexedAccess)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#no-unchecked-indexed-access)

By the way, the same issue is with arrays. If you access the array by index, you won't get any typescript error, even if that index doesn't exist. Fortunately, this option solves the array issue too.

---

P. S. `4.1` is released - [read more about `noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/#no-unchecked-indexed-access)

Comment: Hm I guess it still works not perfectly. When we change `obj.wqwewqe.toFixed()` to for example `const x = obj.wqwewqe;` there is no error...

Comment: `obj.wqwewqe` type is `number | undefined`, so it's normal that `console.log(obj.wqwewqe)` doesn't return any error.